# How to theme content edit page

Tags: theming

I themed page to create custom type node and named it `page--node--add--book.tpl.php`
It works well, but when I tried to theme content edit page and named it `page--node--edit--book.tpl.php`
nothing happening. Help to fix this.

Tried suggestions:

```
function bookhive_theme() {
  return array(
    'book_node_form' => array(
        'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
        'template' => 'book-node-form',
        'render element' => 'form',
    ),
  );
}
```

and 
suggestion from here

```
http://www.wdtutorials.com/how-to-override-forms-using-custom-template-drupal-tutorial/7
```

Comment: What you have defined in template.php for this?

Comment: I tried suggestion from here, http://www.wdtutorials.com/how-to-override-forms-using-custom-template-drupal-tutorial/7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I find an answer. In my case the proper theme suggestion was html--node--edit.tpl.php I used [theme debug mode](https://www.drupal.org/node/223440#theme-debug) to find it.

Also, to make page--node--edit.tpl.php works I need to delete my page--contenttype.tpl.php file. To customize my content type page I just used simple check in page.tpl.php `if($node->type == 'book'):`

```
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- CALL: theme('html') -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * html--node--edit.tpl.php
   * html--node--209.tpl.php
   * html--node--%.tpl.php
   * html--node.tpl.php
   x html.tpl.php
-->
```

Answer (score 1):

**page--node--edit--book.tpl.php** isn't a valid theme template suggestion. From the d.o. D7 [Template docs](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656) for **page.tpl.php**...

> The list of suggested template files is in order of specificity based
>   on internal paths. One suggestion is made for every element of the
>   current path, though numeric elements are not carried to subsequent
>   suggestions. For example, "http://www.example.com/node/1/edit" would
>   result in the following suggestions:
>
> 1. page--node--edit.tpl.php
> 2. page--node--1.tpl.php
> 3. page--node.tpl.php
> 4. page.tpl.php

If you're looking to theme a node edit page, use **page--node--edit.tpl.php**.

Comment: oh, I tried page--node--edit.tpl.php but, thats not work too. at least for me.

Comment: Two things to note why it might not work: You need to clear the Drupal cache / You're using the administration theme for page editing (i.e. the ***Use the administration theme when editing or creating content*** on theme administration page).

Comment: I use Devel to rebuild theme registry on every page reload, I cleared cache manually few times and I check this from regular user account.

Comment: page--node--edit.tpl.php works only with page like website.com/node/edit but not with node/1/edit

Comment: *website.com/node/edit* would not be a valid path in Drupal.